# Exporting PHP Array into Email Body

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, forms

I have put together a contact form at:
http://www.codesign-media.com/tunnels/confirm-booking.html

I've added a click to add text field function to the form, but I'm having trouble printing the array to the body of an email.

Here's the PHP:

```
$Guest_Name = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Guest_Name']));
$Guest_Role = Trim(stripslashes($_POST['Guest_Role']));
```

Including this to print to the body of the email.

```
$Body .= "Guest_Name: ";
$Body .= $Guest_Name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Guest_Role: ";
$Body .= $Guest_Role;
$Body .= "\n";
```

And finally, here is the array:

[image]

I hope it's all easy to understand and I hope I have not been too vague.

Comment: Your guest role and guest name are arrays, but you are treating them as strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guest_Role and Guest_Name are not strings, they're arrays. In your first bit of code when you reference the $_POST array with the key you're returning an array and trying to concatenate it to $Body which won't work. Try this.

```
$Body .= "Guest_Name: ";
$Body .= $Guest_Name[0];
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Guest_Role: ";
$Body .= $Guest_Role[0];
$Body .= "\n";
```

Notice you're referencing them as arrays with a key of 0. With the screenshot of your print_r above, name will return null (or blank) and role will return "Choose_a_Role".

I'm not sure why they're arrays but if you have multiple guest names with roles and want them all concatenated into $Body you'll have to loop through the array and apply each value.

```
foreach ($Guest_Name as $name) {
    $Body .= "Guest Name: {$name}";
}

foreach ($Guest_Role as $role) {
    $Body .= "Guest Role: {$role}";
}
```